# How to define multiple error handling statements?

Tags: python, try-except

I would like to read a set of `csv` files from URL as dataframes. These files contain a date in their name like `YYYYMMDD.csv` in their names. I need to iterate over a set of predefined dates and read the corresponding file into a Python.
Sometimes the file does not exist and an error as follows is thrown:

> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

What I would do in this situation is to add one day to the date like turning `2020-05-01` to `2020-05-02` and in case of throwing the aforementioned error I would add 2 days to the date or at most 3 days until there is a url available without an error.
I would like to know how I can write it in a program maybe with nested `try` - `except` where if adding 1 day to the date leads to a URL without error the subsequent steps are not executed.

As I don't have the data I will use the following URL as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
s = requests.get(url).content
c = pd.read_csv(s)
```

Here the file being read is `medals.csv`. If you try `madels.csv` or `modals.csv` you will get the error I am talking about. So I need to know how I can control the errors in 3 steps by replacing the file name until I get the desired dataframe like first we try `madels.csv` resulting in an error, then `models.csv` also resulting in an error and after that `medals.csv` which result in the desired output.

My problem is that sometimes the modification I made to the file also fails in `except` so I need to know how I can accommodate a second modification.

Comment: I'm not sure what else we could tell you than to use a try/except statement which you already know. Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with recursion? It looks to me as if you should use a simple loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason I asked this question is sometimes also `except` fails and I would like to learn how to come up with a second or third choice.

Comment: In the original problem I could use recursion to add the dates one by one. You are right in the sample example it is not quite useful.

Comment: I can use a for loop to read the dates in the original problem but as soon as one throws and error everything falls apart.

Comment: In your code, what you need to do is put the necessary error-recovery code in the except block. And if that error recovery code might raise an exception too, then use a try/except inside the except. And except is not an exit or a failure, it's a chance for you to write the logic that needs to apply when that exception got raised.

Comment: In your case, it sounds like you need a loop on the date, which increments the date when there's an exception (ideally, be specific, just do that on the right type of exception) and breaks out of the loop if there was no exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "`except` fails"? It's more likely you are failing to use it correctly, and we can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I think I got the concept of `except` wrong. As I put an expression (trying the next day) in the except exactly in the same way I would put it in `try` which is seemingly wrong.

Comment: @chepner Yes I think you are right. I got the concept wrong. So in case try fails and I would like to make modification and try again should I create another `try` - `except in the except part?

Comment: You are going to have to show an example of how you are trying to use `try` in your question.

Comment: Consider the answerw below, check the statements in the `try`, I modified it and use it in `except` as well which I now realize was very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do any nested `try-except` blocks, all you need is one `try-except` and a `for` loop.

First, function that tries to read a file (returns content of the file, or `None` if the file is not found):

```py
def read_file(fp):

    try:
        with open(fp, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            return text
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

Then, function that tries to find a file from a predefined date (example input would be `'20220514'`). The functions tries to read content of the file with the given date, or dates up to 3 days after it:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def read_from_predefined_date(date):

    date_format = '%Y%m%d'
    date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format)

    result = None
    for i in range(4):

        date_to_read = date + timedelta(days=i)
        date_as_string = date_to_read.strftime(date_format)
        fp = f'data/{date_as_string}.csv'
        result = read_file(fp)

        if result:
            break

    return result
```

To test, e.g. create a `data/20220515.csv` and run following code:

```py
d = '20220514'
result = read_from_predefined_date(d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer. Can I rewrite the custom function above with pandas? like using `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Sure, you can rewrite it any way you wish. The important part is the `try-except` logic.

Comment: It's probably better to just let the exception propagate than to return `None` if there's an error reading the file. The caller still has to check *something* (catch the error or check if `read_file` returns `None`), so you may as well simplify the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

here's a simple function that given that URL will do exactly what you ask. Be aware that a slight change in the input url can lead to a few errors so make sure the date format is exactly what you mentioned. In any case:

Notes: [URL Parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

```python
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def url_next_day(url):
    # if the full url is passed I suggest you would use urllib parse but 
    # urllib parse but here's a workaround 
    filename = url.rstrip("/").split("/")[-1]
    date=dt.datetime.strptime(filename.strip(".csv"),"%Y%m%d").date()
    date_plus_one_day= date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    new_file_name= dt.datetime.strftime(date_plus_one_day,"%Y%m%d")+".csv"
    url_next_day=url.replace(filename,new_file_name)

    return url_next_day

for url in list_of_urls:
    try:
        s = requests.get(url).content
        c = pd.read_csv(s)  
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Invalid URL: {url}. The error: {e}. Trying the days after...")
        for _ in range(3): #because you want at most 3 days after
            try:
                url=url_next_day(url)
                s = requests.get(url).content
                c = pd.read_csv(s)
                break
            except Exception:
                pass
        else:
             print("No file available in the days after. Moving on")
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Beat me to it! Good answer. I'll discard what I was starting to write, you've done a much nicer job than what I was working on.

Comment: Small change suggestion: in the inner loop, you should add a `break` statement after `c = pd.read_csv(s)` so that the loop can stop as soon as a url is successfully downloaded.

Comment: And then that for loop needs an `else:` block to tell the user you're giving up completely.

Comment: Happy to hear that as a rookie from such a senior member around here :). Of course the `break` makes total sense, even better than the message bellow the Exception. I'll edit it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer Daniel, I really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: @joanis It is indeed an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have enough changes I want to recommend on top of [@Daniel Gonçalves's initial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73058461/3216427) that I'm going to post them as a second answer.

1- The loop trying additional days needs to break when it got a hit, so it doesn't keep going.

2- That loop needs an `else:` block to handle the complete failure case.

3- It is best practice to catch only the exception you mean to catch and know how to handle. Here a `urllib.error.HTTPError` means a failure to fetch the page, but an other exception would mean something else is wrong with the program, and it would be best not to catch that, so you would notice it and fix your program when that happens.

The result:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    try:
        s = requests.get(url).content
        c = pd.read_csv(s)  
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print(f"Invalid URL: {url}. The error: {e}. Trying the days after...")
        for _ in range(3): #because you want at most 3 days after
            try:
                url = url_next_day(url)
                s = requests.get(url).content
                c = pd.read_csv(s)
                break
            except urllib.error.HTTPError:
                print(f"Also failed to fetch {url}...")
        else:
            # this block is only executed if the loop never breaks
            print("No file available in the days after. Moving on.")
            c = None  # or an empty data frame, or whatever won't crash the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. Everything is clear and I realized I got the concept wrong also.